# How can one store a mm/dd/yy formatted date as text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project to help manipulate a long (100,000+) column of dates to store as text in "mm/dd/yy" format. The dates are currently stored as long, but get formatted as mm/dd/yyyy in my current attempt. When I convert them to text via VBA they of course switch back to their long form.

What I am looking for is similar to the function =TEXT(Cell, "mm/dd/yy") + Copy Paste Values. However, using Application.WorksheetFunction.Text is just keeping the date format. There is an unpictured column called Copy Attempt that is not pictured that is just blank.

[image]

Here's my sample code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Format_Date()

Dim getString As String
Dim getLong As Long
Dim initialRowCount As Long
Dim stringRange As Range
Dim columnFromId As Integer
Dim columnToId As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer


'Get last row
initialRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Find "Formatted Record Date Column"

 getString = "Formatted Record Date"
    Set stringRange = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=getString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    columnFromId = stringRange.Column
    
 getString = "Copy Attempt"
    Set stringRange = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=getString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    columnToId = stringRange.Column

'Convert Format to Text

 For startRow = 2 To initialRowCount
      getString = CStr(Cells(startRow, columnFromId))
      Cells(startRow, columnToId) = WorksheetFunction.Text(getString, "mm/dd/yy")
      
    Next startRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want a column in the worksheet with "mm/dd/yy" dates stored as text, not as dates that are merely formatted like that. If that's correct it has a simple solution. Format the target column as text **BEFORE** copying the correctly formatted date.

Don't worry about the Formatted Record Date column (Col B), just start with the date value, format it as desired, and copy it to the (already formatted as text) column.

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Record Date | Formatted Record Date | Copy Attempt |
| **2** | 45108 | 7/1/2023 | 07/01/23 |
| **3** | 45108 | 7/1/2023 | 07/01/23 |
| **4** | 45108 | 7/1/2023 | 07/01/23 |
| **5** | 45111 | 7/4/2023 | 07/04/23 |
| **6** | 45111 | 7/4/2023 | 07/04/23 |
| **7** | 45111 | 7/4/2023 | 07/04/23 |

```
Option Explicit

Sub Format_Date()
    Dim getString As String
    Dim getLong As Long
    Dim initialRowCount As Long
    Dim stringRange As Range
    Dim columnFromId As Integer
    Dim columnToId As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim wksh As Worksheet
    
    'Get last row
    initialRowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Find "Formatted Record Date Column"
    getString = "Formatted Record Date"
    Set stringRange = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=getString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    columnFromId = stringRange.Column
    
    getString = "Copy Attempt"
    Set stringRange = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=getString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    columnToId = stringRange.Column

    With ActiveSheet
        ' Format target column as text
        Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(columnToId)).NumberFormat = "@"
        
        ' Convert formatted date to Text
        For startRow = 2 To initialRowCount
            getLong = .Cells(startRow, columnFromId)  ' Start with the actual date value
            .Cells(startRow, columnToId) = WorksheetFunction.Text(getLong, "mm/dd/yy")
        Next startRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure of the input and output `NumberFormat` of your cells, but there are only two main options for each. You should keep only one of the blocks marked with A.1 and A.2, and one of B.1 and B.2.

I have refactored other parts of your code, too: always qualify your references (e.g. `wsh.Cells` and not just `Cells`), use `WorksheetFunction.Match` instead of `Find`, etc.

Please also note that the output cell will contain `/` (slash) characters as date separator and not `.` (dots) only if that is the set in the user's regional settings.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Format_Date()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet: Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace the name or refer to ActiveSheet
    Dim colFrom As Long: colFrom = WorksheetFunction.Match("Formatted Record Date", wsh.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Dim colTo As Long: colTo = WorksheetFunction.Match("Copy Attempt", wsh.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Dim rowCurrent As Long: For rowCurrent = 2 To wsh.Cells(wsh.Rows.Count, colFrom).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim cellFrom As Range: Set cellFrom = wsh.Cells(rowCurrent, colFrom)
        Dim cellTo As Range: Set cellTo = wsh.Cells(rowCurrent, colTo)
        
        ' A.1) If the source is stored as a number (actually, Double, not Long), like in the Record Format column
        Dim dat As Date: dat = cellFrom.Value
        
        ' A.2) If the source is stored as text in scrambled format
        Dim stupidOrder() As String: stupidOrder = Split(cellFrom.Value, "/")
        Dim dat As Date: dat = DateTime.DateSerial(CInt(stupidOrder(2)), CInt(stupidOrder(0)), CInt(stupidOrder(1)))
        
        ' B.1) If you want to store it as a number, and keep its parts appearing in the worst order in widespread use
        cellTo.Value = dat
        cellTo.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" ' Or "m/d/yy", which has the same flaw
        
        ' B.2) If you want to store it as text, in a format where its constituents appear in an illogical sequence
        cellTo.NumberFormat = "@"
        cellTo.Value = Format(dat, "mm/dd/yyyy") ' Or "m/d/yy", which is equally irrational
        
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put this together. I learned quite a bit from it on a better practices for qualifying references.